# How specific should exception classes be?

Tags: php, exception

As a rule I try to avoid throwing instances of Exception, because this doesn't convey much information about what went wrong.

But I'm finding that I'm getting a fair number of empty Exception classes, which look like this...

```
class DataNotFoundException extends Exception {
   // just a tagging class
}
```

So functionally the class is identical to Exception. The only functional significance is I can now do this...

```
try {
    ... some code which throws exceptions ...
} catch (DataNotFoundException $dnfe) {
    ... do stuff ...
} catch (OtherException $oe) {
    ... do other stuff ...
}
```

My question is, where is the balance between having a huge number of tiny Exception classes and just throwing instances of Exception. Does anyone have any guidelines for when to introduce a new Exception class?

Comment: If you know exactly what kind of exception is being thrown, you can control the error messages that it outputs, override existing functionality and define additional functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad practice to include lots of specific exceptions, but only ones relevant and reproduce able.  If you choose to be very specific with them, it should go in a specific order, as well; going from *very* specific, to general.

```
try {}    catch (CryptographicException e)
{ ...doSomething }

catch (ArgumentOutOfBoundsException e)
{ ...doSomething }

catch (Exception e)
{ ...doSomething }
```

This being attributed to the processing of events, and if a general Exception is first, all others will be skipped.  Having specific exceptions before general ones will help in the idea that you acquire more information from them, as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's really what I wanted to know. I was just concerned I might get a bit overrun with Exception classes, but your "relevant and reproducible" test is a good way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

You must always extend the Exception class when you have difference logic to handle exception. Look for php Spl library, by the way it contains some exception classes, so you don't need to define your own.

Comment: by different logic you mean like in the two catch clauses in the code in my question?

Comment: Ah, SPL is handy - good to have a selection of standard exceptions around!